# Best upper bound on the number of divisors of $n$ that are larger than $N$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for the best upper bound on $$\sum_{\substack{d | n\\ d \geq N}} 1.$$

I know that
$$
d(n) = \sum_{\substack{d | n}} 1 \leq e^{O(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n})}.
$$

For my application, I need something like 
$$\sum_{\substack{d | n\\ d \geq N}} 1 \leq \frac{o(n^{\epsilon})}{\log N} \quad \forall \epsilon > 0.
$$

A reference where the bound can be found or a simple proof would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Johan Andersson at mathoverflow has pointed out that the third display follows from the second. (Thanks.) I am still interested to learn what the best known bound is.

Comment: If $N > n$, the sum is empty. If $N \leq n$, then $1/\log n \leq 1/\log N$.The sum in the third display is less than $d(n)$ which is less than $\exp(O(\log n / \log \log n)$ which is less than $o(n^{\epsilon}) / \log n$.